# Automatic push notification Cordova on android

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

I'm building a cordova app for android. I need a notification to the user when the database is updated even if they don't have the app open. It's possible? How to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically notifications provide short, timely information about events in your app while it's not in use. For an introduction to how notifications appear on Android, see the Notifications Overview. For sample code that uses notifications.The code on this uses the NotificationCompat APIs from the Android support library. These APIs allow you to add features available only on newer versions of Android while still providing compatibility back to Android 4.0 (API level 14). However, some new features such as the inline reply action result in a no-op on older versions.

Add the support library
Although most projects created with Android Studio include the necessary dependencies to use NotificationCompat, you should verify that your module-level build.gradle file includes the following dependency:

dependencies {
implementation "com.android.support:support-c
compat:28.0.0"
}

You can see more info here:
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels